# Why is the local storage value clear after a refresh?

Tags: javascript

```js
const expenseForm = document.querySelector(".tracker-form"),
      expenseName = document.querySelector(".tracker-name"),
      expenseDate = document.querySelector(".tracker-date"),
      expenseAmount = document.querySelector(".tracker-amount"),
      expenseTable = document.querySelector(".tracker-table");

const expenseArray = [];
const EXPENSE_LS = "expense";

function saveExpense() {
    localStorage.setItem(EXPENSE_LS, JSON.stringify(expenseArray));
}

function loadExpense() {
    const loadedExpense = localStorage.getItem(EXPENSE_LS);
    if (loadedExpense !== null) {
        const parsedExpense = JSON.parse(loadedExpense);
        createRow();
        parsedExpense.forEach(expense => {
            paintExpense(expense);
        });
    }
}

function createRow() {
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    expenseTable.appendChild(tr);
}

function paintExpense(text) {
    const expenseObj = {};

    function createData(text) {
        const td = document.createElement("td");
        const tr = document.querySelector("tr");
        expenseTable.lastChild.appendChild(td);
    
        td.innerHTML = text;
    
        if (text === expenseName.value && text !== "") {
            expenseObj.name = text;
        } else if (text === expenseDate.value && text !== "") {
            expenseObj.date = text;
        } else if (text === expenseAmount.value && text !== "") {
            expenseObj.amount = text;
        }
    }

    createRow();
    createData(expenseName.value);
    createData(expenseDate.value);
    createData(expenseAmount.value);

    expenseArray.push(expenseObj);

    saveExpense();
}

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    paintExpense();
    expenseName.value = "";
    expenseDate.value = "";
    expenseAmount.value = "";
}

function init() {
    loadExpense();
    expenseForm.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);
}

init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Expense Tracker</title>
    <link href="expense-tracker.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Expense Tracker</h1>
    <h3>Add A New Item</h3>

    <form class="tracker-form">

        <label for="tracker-name">Name: </label>
        <input class="tracker-name" type="text" placeholder="What did you spend?">

        <label for="tracker-date">Date: </label>
        <input class="tracker-date" type="date">

        <label for="tracker-amount">Amount: </label>
        <input class="tracker-amount" type="text">

        <input class="tracker-button" type="submit" value="Add Expense">

    </form>    

    <table class="tracker-table">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="expense-tracker.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i submit form, three input values are set in localStorage as an object in array. But when i refresh the page, all the value is clear and only the object itself left. I think loadExpense function has a problem but i don't know why. I googled about this problem and almost of them says stringify array when set it in local storage and parse it when i get it so i did it but it doesn't solve this problem. Why is this happen?

Comment: `loadExpense` calls `paintExpense` which in turn calls `saveExpense`. So on page load you are storing an empty array/object into local storage, thus erasing whatever data existed before.

Comment: i'm sorry but why does it erasing data? @Felix Kling

Comment: When the page loads the input fields don't have any values, so you are never assigning to `expenseObj`. Hence you are pushing an empty object to `expenseArray`, and since you are calling `saveExpense`, the array with the empty object will be stored in local storage, ovewriting whatever value existed there before. The core problem is that you are writing to local storage in the same process as you are reading from it. You should separate that.

Comment: Thank you very much:) it really helps me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**:
When doing `init()` it call `loadExpense()` which reads data from local storage and iterates on each item and then `paintExpense(expense);` is getting called with expense as the parameter.

Now in `paintExpense` method, the passed expense object is not getting used to populate the `tr` and `td` rather you are calling

```
createData(expenseName.value);
createData(expenseDate.value);
createData(expenseAmount.value); 
expenseArray.push(expenseObj) // <-- Empty object since the fields are empty on load
```

In this case all these `expenseName, expenseDate, expenseAmount` are empty that is they don't have value on page refresh. So inside createData the value for `expenseObj` is not getting set which means it remains empty.

Now the line  `expenseArray.push(expenseObj);` is pushing empty object in array i.e [{}] which ultimately getting saved in you `localstorage` hence in localstoray empty objects are getting stored.

**Solution**:
Use passed `expenseObj` in `paintExpense` to populate object.

**Sample Code**

```
function loadExpense() {
    const loadedExpense = localStorage.getItem(EXPENSE_LS);
    if (loadedExpense !== null) {
        const parsedExpense = JSON.parse(loadedExpense);
        parsedExpense.forEach(expense => {
            createRow(expense); //<-- Changed to createRow
        });
    }
}

// Added new method to create column
function createColumn(text) {
    const td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = text;
    return td;
}



// Changed createRow to create row and add columns (Replacement of paintExpense)
function createRow(expenseObj) {
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.append(createColumn(expenseObj.name));
    tr.append(createColumn(expenseObj.date));
    tr.append(createColumn(expenseObj.amount));
    expenseTable.appendChild(tr);
}

// Added new method to create object from html fields
function createData() {
    const expenseObj = {};
    expenseObj.name = expenseName.value;
    expenseObj.date = expenseDate.value;
    expenseObj.amount = expenseAmount.amount;
    return expenseObj;
}

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const expenseObj = createData(); //<-- Create data from fields
    expenseArray.push(expenseObj) //<-- Push into expense array
    createRow(expenseObj); //<-- Create complete row with columns
    saveExpense(); //<-- Moved Save from paint
    
    expenseName.value = "";
    expenseDate.value = "";
    expenseAmount.value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **stringify** your data and then put it into **localStorage**.

Example:

```js
var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));
```

Comment: Isn't the OP doing that? `localStorage.setItem(EXPENSE_LS, JSON.stringify(expenseArray));`.

Comment: I'm getting serious déjà vu here, someone (I assume you) posted this on this question before (Which seems to have been deleted and reposted?) And it still doesn't seem at all relevant as they are already doing that.

Comment: i'm sorry i deleted by mistake... @DBS

Comment: i also think i already doing that @Felix Kling